# Import express app in my api controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm using the Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter express template: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

I have an **/app.ts** file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as apiController from './controllers/api';

const app = express();
// ...
app.get('/api', apiController.getApi);
module.exports = app;
```

Now, I need to get a reference to that app object from within **/controllers/api.ts**:

```
const app = require('../app');

export let getApi = (req: Request, res: Response) => {     
    // get a list of all router pathes to display a table of all api endpoints  
    for (const key in app._router.stack) { // TypeError: cannot read property 'stack' of undefined
    }
}
```

a `console.log(app)` shows that app is empty. I suppose it has something to do with circular dependencies. I tried moving the `module.exports = app` to the top, but that doesn't help.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I believe the problem is that `_router` is not defined in [express.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/release-2.3/types/express/index.d.ts). Typically an underscore means it is not a public API and should not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the API docs, `req`, and `res` hold a reference of the Express `app` instance.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.app